# Vue binding to assets to custom attributes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue3, how does one bind a custom HTML attribute to an asset?  The following does not work.

```html
<template>
  <span :data-imageurl="logo" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const logo = new URL("@/assets/img/logo.png");
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using vite, take a look at [static assets section](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets)

Answer (score 0):

@Duannx, you are correct. I need to use a [static assets section](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets).